# Contact form with unique file name

Tags: php, forms, file

I want to create php file for my contact form but whenever they submit I want a different file name.txt.

This is the code. Whenever someone else submits I lose the old one.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];
$file = fopen('contactform.txt', "w+");
$content = $name. PHP_EOL  .$email. PHP_EOL  .$message;
header('Location: http://localhost:8080/site-edits/contact.php');
fwrite($file , $content);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: For me your question is not clear... why you don'use a db to save your data? About your question if you want a file.txt for every form submit you have to create it with a dinamical name.

Comment: $file = fopen('contactform' . date("YmdHisu") .'.txt', "w+");

Comment: or you can append content to one file

Comment: @Sfili_81 this is a project my friend thats why? thats what i'm asked so let me be more clear when they click my submit button i want php to create a file like contact_(random).txt inside with the name email and his message

Comment: @Barry //edit holy god i never thought of that! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Barry said, you could append a timestamp to your name.

PHP also has a [function tempnam](https://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) available that generates a unique filename:

```
$file = fopen(tempnam(".", "contactform.txt"), "w+");
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is add the current date to the file name:

```
$file = fopen('contactform-'.date('YmdHis').'.txt', "w");
```

Alternatively, you can append to the file instead of writing over it.

```
$file = fopen('contactform.txt', "a");
$content = $name. PHP_EOL  .$email. PHP_EOL  .$message .PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
```

Most people use a database (for example MySQL) for this. I'd suggest learning about how to use databases when you get the time.

Comment: I'd put 'u' on the end of the date string, just in case there a couple of forms get submitted at the same time, there should really be a loop too to ensure the name isn't taken I guess

Comment: You'll still have a race condition, which you could solve by using the x (exclusive) fopen flag, but honestly if you're expecting multiple writes per second you should be using a database instead of rolling your own storage layer

Comment: I get the suggestion for database, but as the OP said, the requirement is a unique file... I've not used the x flag before would make a loop more efficient instead of separately checking if the file exists

Answer (score 0):

You can either create new file with different name any time user submits the form or append text in existed file usin `'a'` rather `'w+'`
Like:

```
$file = fopen('contactform.txt', 'a');
```

For more go to [php file handling](https://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete)

Comment: OP stated "a different file", not appending to the same one